# Intersecting Arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, pixel, intersection

Ok, so here is my code. om is the array I'm comparing im to. I'm hoping the array is in the format [b, g, r]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
om=cv2.imread('RGB.png')
om=om.reshape(1,-1,3)

   while True:
      cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      start=time.time()
      while(cam.isOpened()):                  
          ret, im = cam.read()                
          im=cv2.resize(im,(325,240))         
          im= im.reshape(1,-1,3)
```

Ok, so I'm hoping the arrays are based off of all the pixel colours in them and that they are 1D (reshape should have done that?). Duplicates aren't necessary but like, if possible I would like to keep them.

I want to intersect om with im and get the value of the number of elements intersecting. I tried the in1d thing, but it would return Trues and Falses. I'm half wondering if it would be easier to count them?/ the trues.

Also, if I do use the in1d function, does that only count corresponding pixels? (like, that the pixel height and row matter) or is it only pixel bgr? because I am only after bgr.

Basically, I wanna see how many pixels have the same colour value as those in the picture I already have saved.

Btw, I tried using sets, but they were fairly slow and difficult to get into the correct order (I seemed to be getting only one element a set).

Comment: It is unclear what you're exactly trying to do, and it seems the code you show it's just the setup before the actual work, so it doesn't really help. Try to reformulate your problem. About sets, they don't have a notion of order so if order matters it's clearly not what you need.

Answer (score 3):

intersection = [x for x in list_1 if x in list_2]